# Nested ngFor only returns last item on inner ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to loop through firebase RTDB reference to retrieve a list and then use those results in a subsequent firestore query.  the console logs the correct data but my code only displays the last item in the loop in the inside ngFor.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

```
this.ref = firebase.database().ref('stations/');
    this.ref.on('value', resp => {
      this.infos = [];
      this.infos = snapshotToArray(resp);

    });
    const snapshotToArray = snapshot => {
      let returnArr = [];

      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          let item = childSnapshot.val();
          item.key = childSnapshot.key;
          returnArr.push(item.StationtName);
          let sku = item.StationtName;

          this.queues = this.afs.collection('projects', ref => ref.where('station', '==', item.StationtName)).valueChanges()

      });

      return returnArr;
    }
```

html:

```
              <div *ngFor="let info of infos">
                                {{info}} 
                    <div *ngFor="let queue of queues | async">

                        <ion-button>  {{queue.SKU}}</ion-button>

                    </div> 

               </div>
```

json and new error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[
  {
    "SKU": "908897",
    "buyerEmail": "m",
    "comments": "c",
    "createdAt": 1550285024451,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "The Warehouse",
    "timeTest": "Fri Feb 15 2019",
    "type": "Project"
  }
]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

this.infos:

```
["Lathe", "Press 1", "Press 2", "Mill 1", "Mill 2", "Ready", "Plasma", "Grinding", "Grinding", "Flange shop", "the office", "The Warehouse"]
```

added an .subscribe() to this.queues and got the correct info logged to the console on every loop. The associated projects for each station are printed to the console.  Here is one of them;

```
["09987", "66553", "3", "98774", "4", "987654321", "1", "6533343434343"]
```

these are all SKU's that are associated with each station.

Here is the subscribe code I added to get the value of the observable, now Im getting another error though:

```
.subscribe(data=>{
                  console.log(data);


                  this.items = data.map(function (obj) {
                    return obj.SKU;
                  });

                  console.log(this.items);
                  // this.stationArr.push(this.item);

                 })
```

The error I'm getting now is:

```
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

And this in the the chrome inspector:

```
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null
}-->
```

current output:

```
Lathe
----- 908897
Press 1
----- 908897
Press 2
----- 908897
Mill 1
----- 908897
Mill 2
----- 908897
Ready
----- 908897
Plasma
----- 908897
Grinding
----- 908897
Grinding
----- 908897
Flange shop
----- 908897
the office
----- 908897
The Warehouse
----- 908897

desired output:
Lathe
----- 908897
Press 1
----- 123432,5476344
Press 2
----- empty
Mill 1
----- 0987654, 7777777, 673654
Mill 2
----- 12321
Ready
----- 909090990, 878787878, 67767
etc.
```

each station has a SKU associated, but my code displays the same one for each station.

json file:

```
[{
    "id": "0rikFyAEt4Zg83sPeUNG",
    "SKU": "88",
    "buyerEmail": "",
    "comments": "",
    "createdAt": 1550297319125,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Press 1",
    "timeTest": "Sat Feb 16 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "1UJftXBqdmvjwJAs2XO5",
    "SKU": "77777e7e7",
    "buyerEmail": "b",
    "comments": "c",
    "createdAt": 1550291447696,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Lathe",
    "timeTest": "Fri Feb 15 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "1aFkV5z0JBzfii0edQCd",
    "SKU": "911111111",
    "buyerEmail": "matt@duhon.com",
    "comments": "comment",
    "createdAt": 1550286952568,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Grinding",
    "stations": ["Addy"],
    "timeTest": "Fri Feb 15 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "5BylWSmtH02v8oCq7T2B",
    "SKU": "123456789",
    "buyerEmail": "MAtts",
    "comments": "comment",
    "createdAt": 1550372243065,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Press 1",
    "timeTest": "Sat Feb 16 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "BVNaMjK5oqSslnfE6Uar",
    "SKU": "11111111",
    "buyerEmail": "",
    "comments": "",
    "createdAt": 1550290392880,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Mill",
    "timeTest": "Fri Feb 15 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "HvxQF4suTBaiCwpWgf9D",
    "SKU": "908897",
    "buyerEmail": "m",
    "comments": "c",
    "createdAt": 1550285024451,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "The Warehouse",
    "timeTest": "Fri Feb 15 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "KfJ4qvVyDzVwFxIeMRzM",
    "SKU": "09987",
    "buyerEmail": "",
    "comments": "",
    "createdAt": 1550286034246,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Ready",
    "timeTest": "Fri Feb 15 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "MrrioE5IHpImz52qnHW5",
    "SKU": "1211221",
    "buyerEmail": "",
    "comments": "",
    "createdAt": 1550290371569,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Lathe",
    "timeTest": "Fri Feb 15 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "TczmkayGuWonT6SQZf6F",
    "SKU": "3",
    "buyerEmail": "",
    "comments": "3 years old yo!",
    "createdAt": 1550298020154,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Ready",
    "timeTest": "Sat Feb 16 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "ZspOz31o0uYT0Msull5J",
    "SKU": "909987",
    "buyerEmail": "matt@duhon.com",
    "comments": "comment",
    "createdAt": 1550286926441,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Packaging",
    "timeTest": "Fri Feb 15 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "hXC1uswgbW1UVTfVD96k",
    "SKU": "98774",
    "buyerEmail": "matt@duhon.com",
    "comments": "comments",
    "createdAt": 1550296878271,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Ready",
    "timeTest": "Sat Feb 16 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "jeR8wCiPdCwObZvajT04",
    "SKU": "4",
    "buyerEmail": "matt",
    "comments": "comments",
    "createdAt": 1550298181612,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Ready",
    "timeTest": "Sat Feb 16 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "lx2Hh3rpQ1rLkGHAgEzo",
    "SKU": "987654321",
    "buyerEmail": "yomama",
    "comments": "com mints",
    "createdAt": 1550296669267,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Ready",
    "timeTest": "Fri Feb 15 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "qAYSdYYC2wxBwYDYI71T",
    "SKU": "1",
    "buyerEmail": "",
    "comments": "",
    "createdAt": 1550297026128,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Ready",
    "timeTest": "Sat Feb 16 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}, {
    "id": "sBXhW6lPaYtUn4fz5Gsf",
    "SKU": "6533343434343",
    "buyerEmail": "MAtt",
    "comments": "Comment",
    "createdAt": 1550372086063,
    "queue": 1,
    "station": "Ready",
    "timeTest": "Sat Feb 16 2019",
    "type": "Project"
}]
```

Comment: Would you mind providing the json data you are getting. The code looks fine to me

Comment: Sure, I actually just got a new error when trying to get you some json. see edit

Comment: I suppose, the object you shared `queue`. The error seems to be because you are trying `*ngFor`  on somr string value. Can you share `infos` and  `queues `.

Comment: added infos, see edit.  working on queues but its an observable and I'm having trouble getting a value from the console.

Comment: added log from queues.  see edit

Comment: `InvalidPipeArgument` because `async` works on `observables` only. Let me create a sample demo anh then you can edit it and show what you want

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz, will be easy to identify the problem

Comment: trying now, trouble hooking up firebase

Answer (score 0):

As per you code check this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnk85y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) code where you can see the nested `*ngFor`

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let info of infos">{{info}}
    <ol *ngFor="let queue of queues | async">{{queue.SKU}}</ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, and forgive me if I wasn't clear, my problem is getting the right data displayed in the view.  I am logging the correct data on every loop, but in the html only the last iteration is displayed on each loop.  in other words, 'Lathe' shows the same SKU as every other station.  I'm posting my current output in an edit with more detail now.

Comment: @MacD Provide me exact json file otherwise I wont be able to help much any further. I can't see any `SKU` with value `0987654, 7777777, 673654` as you have updated in question. Please fork and replicate the issue in my provided demo and let me know

Comment: I'm trying to set up a skackbliz now hooked up to firebase so you can see the exact problem, and yes that was just some dummy data I made up.

Comment: unfortunately I'm still having issues getting it working so bare with me

Comment: cant get the stackblitz to work but i did post the actual json file

Comment: @MacD unable to open the link. Not sure what's wrong :(

Comment: For some reason I can’t get it to work:/. Thanks for your help here anyway @shashank.  I’ll try again this evening and post another one..

Comment: @MacD feel free  to update the question and let me know in comments